# Remove a random chain of characters with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I would like to write a script which would find some specific datas in a web page and return it in a pop up box

The code below works perfectly for a given string of characters. The issue is that each time a new product its checked, the string will change.

This is how it would look when checking the page source:

```
<randomcharacters<!---->evenmorerandomcharacters<!----> 9999 <!----></div>
```

There will always be 2 `<!---->` before the number I want to grab and `<!----></div>` after the number I want to grab. The number of random characters before the number I want to grab is not consistent either

```
tell application "Safari"

    set unitsgrab to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('theclassIwant')[0].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
end tell

set units to ""
set theSource to unitsgrab
property leftEdge : "randomcharacters<!---->evenmorerandomcharacters<!---->"
property rightEdge : "<!----></div>"
try
    set saveTID to text item delimiters
    set text item delimiters to leftEdge
    set classValue to text item 2 of theSource
    set text item delimiters to rightEdge
    set units to text item 1 of classValue
    set text item delimiters to saveTID
    units
end try



display dialog "Units:" & (units)
```

What I actually want to do is tell the script to delete everything up to the second `<!---->` in order to only have 9999 display in my example above

Comment: Given your example code If you replace all the lines of code from `set units to ""` up to and including `end try` with the following one line: `set units to do shell script "/usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"<!---->\" } ; { print $3 }' <<< " & quoted form of unitsgrab & " | xargs"` that will give you `9999`. This shells-out to `awk` and the last pipe to `xargs` removes any leading/trailing space characters.

Comment: @RobC, Why use `& " | xargs"` when `awk` can do it all by adding `gsub(/ /, \"\",  $3) ;` in front of `print  $3` thus making the extra pipe and additional external command needless?

Comment: `set units to do shell script "awk -F \"<!---->\"  '{ gsub(/ /, \"\",  $3); print $3 }' <<< " & quoted form of unitsgrab`

Comment: @user3439894 - Simply because I wrote that comment via my mobile phone (i.e. no computer to test on) and I was unsure of the syntax. But yes, utilizing `awk` to also remove the _leading and trailing_ white space is another option. However, please note that your example strips all white space - including any interior space(s). It seems that [two successive `gsub` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk#answer-20601021) are required for stripping leading and trailing spaces _only_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize AppleScripts [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command to shell out to [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Here are a couple of examples:

---

1. **Example A :** ***Exclude all spaces***

   This example is as per [@user3439894's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804222/remove-a-random-chain-of-characters-with-applescript#comment-102061501), (thankyou @user3439894 !), which improves upon the example given in [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804222/remove-a-random-chain-of-characters-with-applescript#comment-102050335). This avoids piping to [`xargs`](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html) and instead strips spaces via `awk` too.

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
     set unitsgrab to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('theclassIwant')[0].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
   end tell

   set units to do shell script "awk -F \"<!---->\" '{ gsub(/ /, \"\", $3); print $3 }' <<< " & quoted form of unitsgrab

   display dialog "Units:" & units
   ```

   However, this example does strip all leading, trailing, and interior space(s). For instance, lets say the string assigned to the `unitsgrab` variable is:

   ```
   <rand56omcharacters<!---->evenmorera11ndomcharacters<!---->  99 9 9 <!---->
                                                              ^^  ^ ^ ^
   ```

   <sub>Note the additional spaces indicated by the caret symbols (`^`).</sub>

   The resultant value assigned to the `units` variable will be:

   ```
   9999
   ```
2. **Example B :** ***Exclude leading and trailing whitespace only***

   The following example removes leading/trailing whitespace, and preserves any interior whitespace:

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
     set unitsgrab to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('theclassIwant')[0].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
   end tell

   set units to do shell script "awk -F \"<!---->\" '{ gsub(/^[ \\t]+/, \"\", $3); gsub(/[ \\t]+$/, \"\",$3); print $3 }' <<< " & quoted form of unitsgrab

   display dialog "Units:" & units
   ```

   This time, lets say the string assigned to the `unitsgrab` variable is:

   ```
   <rand56omcharacters<!---->evenmorera11ndomcharacters<!---->  12 3  4 <!----></div>    
                                                              ^^  ^ ^^ ^
   ```

   <sub>Again note the additional spaces indicated by the caret symbols (`^`).</sub>

   The resultant value assigned to the `units` variable will be:

   ```
   12 3  4
     ^ ^^
   ```

   Note the interior whitespace(s) has been preserved, only the leading and trailing whitespace has been removed. *(The caret symbols exist here for illustrative purposes only)*

---

To better understand the `awk` commands above I recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk#answer-20601021). The notable differences here is that some additional character escaping (i.e. using a backslash `\`) is required in these AppleScript examples to ensure valid syntax. For instance; double quotes `"` become `\"` and `\t` become `\\t`.

---

**EDIT:**

3. **Example C :** ***Preserve all whitespace***

   If you wanted to preserve all leading, trailing, and inner whitespace then omit the `gsub` part. For instance:

   ```
   tell application "Safari"
     set unitsgrab to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('theclassIwant')[0].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
   end tell

   set units to do shell script "awk -F \"<!---->\" '{ print $3 }' <<< " & quoted form of unitsgrab

   display dialog "Units:" & units
   ```

Comment: In 2. **Example B :** **_Exclude leading and trailing whitespace only_**, you do not necessarily need to use two separate `gsub` _commands_, as one with the following `regex` handles it: `awk -F '<!---->'  '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, \"\", $3); print $3}'`

Comment: @user3439894 - Thanks for your commentary/suggestions. Yes, I saw the use of the single `gsub` in [the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600982/trim-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string-in-awk#answer-20601998) that I linked to too. As the adage says: _"There's more than one way to cook an egg.."_ `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've represented to data correctly, I don't think you need to worry about the random characters. Rewrite your text item delimiters routine like so:

```
set tid to my text item delimiters
set my text item delimiters to "<!---->"
set classValue to text item 3 of theSource
set my text item delimiters to tid
```

`text item 3` should always be the text between the 2 and 3 occurrences of the delimiter string.